# Instapy problem,why doesnt the code work?

Tags: python, function, module, instagram, instapy

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
import time

my_username = '_georgekazaras'
my_password = 'mypassword'

def job():
    session = InstaPy(username=my_username,
                      password=my_password)

    with smart_run(session):
        session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,
                                        delimit_by_numbers=True,
                                        max_followers=90000000000000,
                                        min_followers=1,
                                        min_following=30)
        session.set_do_follow(True, precentage=100)
        session.set_dont_like(['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6', 'tag7'])
        session.like_by_tags(['cars', 'chess', 'sports'])

job()
```

I tried getting the code out of the function to see if it helps but it didnt, is the library not working anymore ,is iit maybe because of my instagram settings or is it something about the code ?

Comment: You have a typo in set_do_follow(percentage not precentage)

Comment: it still dont work,do i have to run it from my terminal?

Comment: Try to set the max followers to a smaller number. Or post the traceback error here

Comment: still no, it it maybe the library?

Comment: Can be last update is 10 months ago.. without traceback i dont know

Comment: do you know any library other than selenium, for something like this?

Comment: Instaloader or PyInstagramBot. But never tried out. Sorry that i'm not able to help you